# Php file_put_contents with multiple files

Tags: php, arrays, json

I am using `file_put_contents` to create and add info to a json file. This works successfully, however I need to create two files with different names (`title.json` and `dates.json`) - is this possible?

The reason I need to do this is because I am using twitter typeahead and it seems to only work with separate json files.

It works with a single file i.e;

> file_put_contents(URL . '/title.json', json_encode($data));

However not with this;

> file_put_contents(URL . '/title.json', '/dates.json',
>   json_encode($data));

I receive the following error message;

> Warning: file_put_contents() expects parameter 3 to be long, string
>   given in C:\xampp\htdocs... on line 23

```
$sql = ("SELECT DISTINCT pub_id, title, place_name, party_name, publication_date FROM vw_ft_search");

$data = array();

while($row = $result->fetch_assoc())
{
    $data[] = array('title' => utf8_encode($row['title']),
                    'pub_id' => utf8_encode($row['pub_id']),
                    'place_name' => utf8_encode($row['place_name']),
                    'party_name' => utf8_decode($row['party_name']),
                    'publication_date'  => $row['publication_date']);
}

file_put_contents(URL . '/title.json','/dates.json', json_encode($data)); //line 23
```

I am probably missig something very easy, any advice is appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

file_put_contents only accepts one file. Use a loop to insert in all files ->

```
$files = array('/title.json', '/dates.json');
```

then iterate through $files:

```
foreach($files as $file)
{
    file_put_contents(URL.$file, json_encode($data));
}
```

Comment: thanks @SidiaStudios I tried what you suggested however now I receive the error `Warning: file_put_contents(/dates.json): failed to open stream: Permission denied in C:\xampp\htdocs\... on line 27`

Comment: You dont have permission to write to /dates.json (which would be servers basefolder -> dates.json) Maybe you meant URL.'/dates.json' there too?

Comment: yea perfect I had to type `$files = array(URL . '/title.json', URL . '/dates.json');` in order to get it working - may thanks!